# Finding pair of Positive Integers $(m,n)$ such that $1!+2!+3!+4!+\cdots +n!=m^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

We need to find pair of $$(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^+, ~~\text{so that}~~~~ (1!+2!+3!+4!+\cdots+n!)=m^2 $$

I did a variation of this problem once, with multiplication in between, but it has addition here.

But this one has stumped me for a while now, the only solution i came up with hand are$(3,3)$ and $(1,1)$

I believe there is some clever trick to get it done, so  i welcome all **Hints** on how to solve it, Full length solutions are discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that a perfect square doesn't end in $\ 3$. For your convenience, there are only $\ 2 $ values of $\ n$, and those are $\ n=1, 3$. Hope it helps. If not, I will put the solution.

The above is a part of the hint. Complete hint would be to notice that the unit digits of $\ n!, n \geq 5$ is equal to $\ 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Just on the same path as the previous one. Please note that $1! + 2! + 3! + 4!$ ends in $3$. And if $n \geqslant 5$, then let's define the notation $\mathscr{U}_{S}$ as the unit
place value of $S$ where  $$ S = \sum_{k = 1}^n k! \quad \text{and} \quad \mathscr{U}_S = 3 $$
The rest is trivial, as no perfect square can have the last term $3$, thus...