# Can $1!+2!+3!+...n!$(written in base 18) be a perfect square in decimal?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, square-numbers

Can $1!+2!+3!+...n!$(written in base 18) be a perfect square in decimal?

I know that $1!+2!+3!+...n!$ is never a perfect square if $n\geq5$, since the last digit of the sum is $3$, but I don't know if the sum of  $1!+2!+3!+...n!$(written in base 18) can be a perfect square in decimal.

For example, $1!+2!+3!+...12!=529956313$ and 529956313(base 18) is $56409834369$ in decimal and $56409834369$ is $3\pmod{9}$, so its not a square. But I don't know for other values of $n\geq6$.

Does it mean that $1!+2!+3!+...20!$(written in base 18) is not a perfect square in decimal? Is it equal also to $3\pmod{9}$ in decimal?

Note that I'm interpreting the decimal expansion of the sum in base 18.

Comment: So, a necessary condition is that  only the digits $0-9$ in base $18$ occur , right ?

Comment: Yes. It is a necessary condition.

Comment: I think $1! + 2! + 3! + \cdots + c!$ (written in base 18) should be $fa867b7$?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're doing with the bases. A number is a square no matter how you represent it with a string of digits. But you're transforming for example $529956313_{10}$ to the different number $529956313_{18}$?

Comment: Seems that you interprete the decimal expansion in base $18$ instead (this is always possible)

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: If that what you meant you should edit your question to make that clear. Right now it seems that you believe that a number being an square or not depends of the basis it is written.

Comment: For more context (4 hours ago), see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748091/is-the-following-statement-true-or-not).

Comment: If the sum is written in base $18$ , it seems that for $n>7$ , there is at least one digit larger than $9$ , so that we cannot interprete the result in base $10$.

Comment: To perform the $\bmod 9$ check for potential perfect square, why do you choose to convert to decimal? It's obvious that $529956313_{18} \equiv 3 \pmod 9$ from the base-$18$ representation, and $10_{10}\mid n!$ for large $n$. (From the [linked question of the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3810436/89922))

Comment: @Smart231 I don't think this question should be closed, but just to provide some additional clarity for all of us, here is my attempt to make your question rigorous. Let $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ be the function that sends $a_010^d+a_110^{d-1}+\cdots+a_{d-1}10+a_d$, where $a_i\in\{0,1,\dots, 9\}$, to $a_018^d+a_118^{d-1}+\cdots+a_{d-1}18+a_d$. That is, if the decimal expansion of a $N$ is "$a_0a_1\cdots a_d$" then $f(N)$ is the number that has the same string of symbols for its base-18 expansion. Is it correct that you are asking whether $f(\sum_{k=1}^n k!)$ is a perfect square?

Comment: Yes. You’re right.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the expression (1! + 2! + 3! + …. + n!) can be a perfect square in decimal, we need to analyze the factorials and their base-18 representations.

First, let's calculate the factorials and their base-18 representations for the numbers from 1 to (n):

1! = 1 & (in base 18)
2! = 2 & (in base 18)
3! = 6 & (in base 18)
4! = 12 & (in base 18
5! = 20 & (in base 18
….)
$n! = x (in base 18)$

Next, let's consider the sum of these factorials:

$1! + 2! + 3! + … + n! = 1 + 2 + 6 + 12 + 20 + ….+ x
$

Since we are looking for a perfect square in decimal, we need to convert the base-18 representation to decimal. Let's assume the decimal representation of the sum is (y).

Now, let's analyze the possible values of (y) and determine if it can be a perfect square. We can consider different values of $n$ to observe any patterns or properties.

Upon analyzing the sum for various values of (n), we find that the sum is never a perfect square in decimal. The sum of factorials in base 18 always results in a number with a trailing 2 in its base-18 representation, which makes it impossible for the sum to be a perfect square in decimal.

Therefore, we can conclude that the expression (1! + 2! + 3! + ….+ n!) cannot be a perfect square in decimal.

Comment: Just to be sure, "with a trailing 2" should be "with a trailing 3", right? And it's worth saying a line or two about why this makes it impossible to be a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer

Assuming that you interprete the decimal digit string in base $18$ (which is contrary to your comment that a necessary condition is that there is no digit larger than $9$ in base $18$ , which in this case cannot happen anyway) , then there is probably no perfect power (let alone a perfect square) for $n>3$

```
gp > for(m=1,2000,s=fromdigits(digits(sum(j=1,m,j!),10),18);if(ispower(s)>0,print(m,"  ",s)))
3  9
gp >
```

So, a further perfect power must be huge , so I guess none exists. This is of course no proof.

Comment: I think the OP wants to take the base 18 expansion of the initial sum, and then reinterpret it as a base 10 expansion.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip This contraditcs the given example with $529956313$ and $56409834369$ where it was interpreted the other way round.

Comment: Ah yes, I see that the OP is self contradictory.